# Textbox value to a Session variable in JSP

Tags: jsp

I have a simple Jsp page which contains HTML elements,as follows,

```
<tr id="tr-username">
   <td>Username</td>
   <td><input type="text" id="userName"/></td>
</tr>
```

I want to set the value of userName textbox to a session variable.How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly set the value in the session variable from the rendered JSP . Once your form on jsp is submitted then at the servlet/controller you can  do :

```
 String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
   if(userName!=null && !"".equals(userName){ 
         request.getSession().setAttribute("userName",userName);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set session  variable as:

```
<%
   String name = request.getParameter( "textbox name" );
   session.setAttribute( "theName", name );
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
   String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
   if(userName!=null &&
        !"".equals(userName){ 
         session.setAttribute("userName",userName);
   }
%>
<input type="text" id="userName" name="userName"/>
```